# YA trilogy about a girl saving a magic kingdom whose boyfriend becomes part of a tree

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This is probably a long shot but it's been really bugging me trying to figure this out.

I'm searching for a fantasy trilogy where a mortal girl has to save a magic kingdom from fairies or something of the sort.

I distinctly remember in the last book her boyfriend becomes part of a tree of souls/life/etc. I believe each book had a one word title.

Comment: Do you remember any other events? What was her name? What did she look like? Was her boyfriend also mortal? Was she originally from the fantasy land or did she get transported there? Book covers? How was she able to save the magic kingdom?

Answer (score 6):

This is the "[Gemma Doyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemma_Doyle_Trilogy)" trilogy for sure, I think.

From the [Wikipedia character article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Gemma_Doyle_Trilogy_characters):

> During the battle with The Tree Of All Souls, Gemma is stabbed by Amar and her blood is spilled on the ground of the Winterlands, damning her to become one with the Tree. Kartik gives up his life in exchange for Gemma's, taking her place inside of the Tree.

Not matching, the titles of the books are not single words: *A Great and Terrible Beauty*, *Rebel Angels*, and *The Sweet and Far Thing*.

[image: A Great and Terrible Beauty] [image: Rebel Angels] [image: The Sweet and Far Thing]